# The type 'FluentValidation.IValidator' is not an open generic class

Tags: autofac, fluentvalidation

On an ASP.NET Core application I am registering

```
services.Scan(x => x.FromAssembliesOf(typeof(Startup))
  .AddClasses(y => y.AssignableTo(typeof(IValidator)))
  .AsImplementedInterfaces()
  .WithScopedLifetime());
```

I tried to replicate this using Autofac so I used:

```
builder
  .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Startup).Assembly)
  .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IValidator))
  .AsImplementedInterfaces()
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

But I got the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: 
The type 'FluentValidation.IValidator' is not an open generic class or interface type so it won't work with methods that act on open generics.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Am not sure what exactly the `AsClosedTypesOf(Type)` does, but the name (and the error you're getting) suggests it expects an "open" generic type like IList<T>, and registers for all "closed" types like `IList<int>`, `IList<string>` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `AsClosedTypesOf` use a `Where` clause to filter out and register just the types that implement `IValidator`. `AsClosedTypesOf` is specifically there to support open generics. [There are plenty of examples in the Autofac docs to help you out.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html)